# Obtener firmas de documentos PDF

Tags: javascript, opencv

Estoy tratando de obtener las firmas de un documento escaneado. Las firmas están dentro de un recuadro y quiero obtener estas ya sea sin el recuadro o con él.
Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y obtener algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible obtener algo así con opencv u otra librería?

Traté algo como esto pero a las *images* no las reconoce bien. Tal vez el modelo necesita más refinamiento.

```
private void Test() {
      Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("ImgTest.png");
        Mat grayImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        String haarCascadePath = "C:\\ModelTrainning\\cascade\\cascade.xml";
        CascadeClassifier classifier = new CascadeClassifier(haarCascadePath);

        MatOfRect signatures = new MatOfRect();
        classifier.detectMultiScale(image,signatures);

        int i=0;
        for (Rect rect : signatures.toArray()){
            Mat signatureROI = new Mat(image, rect);
            String signatureImagePath = "firma_" + i + ".jpg";
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(signatureImagePath, signatureROI);
            i++;
        }

    }
```